# Getting Error Json Invalid Format While Showing Data In Data-table?

Tags: php, json, datatable

I am showing Address , street, City, Name, Company Name in Data-table, My Database is configured to UTF-8 also I am using google API to parse address into street, city , Pin-code and state. also we are using special character (German, french,...)   for some users but sometime JSON IS IN INVALID FORMAT Error showing while showing in Data-table. I tried converting every field to utf-8 but it isn't working .....

[This is Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bekvu.png)

I know this error is getting because of Non-ASCII characters when i tried deleting Non-ASCII characters it was working but i have to allow non-ASCII character

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect, but without code, examples and exact error messages there is nothing anybody can do.

Comment: I thought this is common error.... but its ok i have put screenshot...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution

I am detecting string encoding format using `mb_detect_encoding($str);` then converting it into utf-8

also for all pages I have mentioned utf-8 encoding for all html source pages.

Now its seems working